# JSON parsing issues

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am getting a JSON but i can't seem to parse it. This is my code:

```
[httpClient postPath:@"" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonDict);

    NSArray *jsonArray = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"sJSON"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[jsonArray class]);
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonArray);
```

The NSLog that prints the class gives me _NSCFString class.

Could it be that it is not really a JSON? Although it really looks like a JSON. Looks like this:

[{"ImageTagID":78,"Xpixel":408,"Ypixel":69,"Xpercent":17}]

Comment: NSLog jsonDict and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have JSON embedded in JSON:

```
{ "sJSON": "[{\"ImageTagID\":78,\"Xpixel\":408,\"Ypixel\":69,\"Xpercent\":17}]" }
```

You'll have to decode "jsonArray" (which is a string) again using NSJSONSerialization then.